# BAT File to find most recent files based on filename

Tags: batch-file

I need to be able to create a bat script to do 3 things:

1. Search for multiple specific filenames in a directory.
2. Find the most recently generated version based on each filename specified.
3. Copy that most file to a new dir.

I am very new to coding in general, so any assistance would be much appreciated.
So far all I have been able to do is figure out how to copy files from one location to another using the below:

```
xcopy /s c:\source\differentfilename1.csv d:\target\

xcopy /s c:\source\differentfilename2.txt d:\target

xcopy /s c:\source\differentfilename3.html d:\target
```

Comment: Please note that SO is not a free code writing service, so share what you have tried so far and describe where you are stuck...

Answer (score 0):

So far I have tried the following and its not copying the files over:

```
ECHO

CD D:\Data\

MKDIR D:\Data\CopyFilesHere

for /R %file in (Filename1.*) DO XCOPY "%file" D:\Data\CopyFilesHere
for /R %file in (Filename2.*) DO XCOPY "%file" D:\Data\CopyFilesHere
for /R %file in (Filename3.*) DO XCOPY "%file" D:\Data\CopyFilesHere
```

I have since noted there are subfolders I need to search through also.